# Printing selected columns from a csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have some code here:

````
with open("dsasa.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:
content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
for row in content:
    print row```
````

I would like to print columns 2, 3, 4 from the csv file in the following format:

`4556 | 432432898904 | Joseph Henry`
`4544 | 54522238904 | Mark Mulligan`

I have two issues which I am encountering. One is that the delimiter pipe (|) is not appearing between the columns. The second issue is that I cannot print the specific columns I want by doing the manual way, ie. `print row[2], row[3], row[4]`

I looked at online info and tried a few different solutions but I can't seem to find the route to get this to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open("dsasa.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:
    content = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in content:
        print "|".join([row[2],row[3],row[4]])
```

The `delimiter` argument within `csv.reader` refers to the input file not the output.

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution very similar to yours just before you posted that. The only difference is that in the last line I put: 

    `print row[2], "|", row[3], "|", row[6], row [7]` 

as I wanted there to be space between each column and no pipe between row 6 and row 7. But for being on the ball, I give the answer to you. I also removed the header using `next(Content, None)`

Answer (score 0):

What does appear between the columns as the delimiter? Are you sure it is '|' and not a comma? I am guessing because you do not have the correct delimiter you cannot use print row[2], row[3], row[4]. Can you post a line of the CSV?

Comment: Where is the sample line from the CSV file?

Comment: I removed the delimiter entirely which now prints the specific rows that I want to print. However, I still want to add the `|` symbol in there.

Comment: Actually, I added a "|" in between each row when printing the statement.